# Jquery custom image slider slider with different image width

Tags: jquery, slider

i have a project to make image slider that has a spec like this:
- infinite loop
- two rows
- when i press next or prev button, slider should move for a width of next image (upcoming image)
my HTML:

```
<div class="mid">
<div class="sliderpos1">
<div class="slidemove">
    <span id="addimage"><img src="img/slider-image-1.jpg"></span>
    <span id="addimage"><img src="img/slider-image-2.jpg"></span>
    <span id="addimage"><img src="img/slider-image-3.jpg"></span>
    <span id="addimage"><img src="img/slider-image-4.jpg"></span>
    <span id="addimage"><img src="img/slider-image-5.jpg"></span>
    <br>
    <span id="addimage"><img src="img/slider-image-6.jpg"></span>
    <span id="addimage"><img src="img/slider-image-7.jpg"></span>
    <span id="addimage"><img src="img/slider-image-8.jpg"></span>
    <span id="addimage"><img src="img/slider-image-9.jpg"></span>
  </div>

    </div>
    <button class="button1" id="prev"></button>
    <button class="button2" id="next"></button>

</div>
```

my CSS:

```
.sliderpos1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    left: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 700px;
    top: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1400px;
}
.sliderpos1 img {
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}

.slidemove {
    position: relative;
}
```

and here si my jquery :

```
$(function () {

    var gallery = $('.slidemove'),
        items = gallery.find('span'),
        len = items.length,
        current = 1,
        first = items.filter(':first'),
        last = items.filter(':last'),
        imgwidth = $('img').last().width(),
        triggers = $('button');

    first.before(last.clone(true));
    last.after(first.clone(true));

    triggers.on('click', function () {
        if (gallery.is(':not(:animated)')) {
            var cycle = false,
                delta = (this.id === "prev") ? -1 : 1;
            gallery.animate({ left: "+=" + (imgwidth * delta) }, function () {
                current += delta;
                cycle = !!(current === 0 || current > len);
                if (cycle) {
                    current = (current === 0) ? len : 1;
                    gallery.css({ right: imgwidth });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I get problem with cloning first and last image and don't know how to do it, also there is a problem to implement upcoming image width to slide it for that size.
If anyone can help with this, would be nice or at least how to clone and display next image.

Comment: Please provide a working jsfiddle :)

Comment: Here is JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jbognar/tycwqj9y/

Comment: Thanks, i'll provide an answer asap

Answer (score 1):

Managed to add some basic clone functionality.

As per comments in js code i leave to you make this work better.

Also fixed an issue with `<br>` element in css.

```
$(function () {

var gallery = $('.slidemove'),
    items = gallery.find('span'),
    len = items.length,
    current = 1,
    first = items.filter(':first'),
    last = items.filter(':last'),
    imgwidth = $('img').last().width(),
    triggers = $('button');

var htmlarr = $(".slidemove").html().split("<br>");
var addtotop = htmlarr[0];
var addtobottom = htmlarr[1];
var appendtotop = $(".slidemove br").prev();
var appendtobottom = $(".slidemove span").last();
//left to you calculate the correct width to add
var widthtoadd = 1400;

triggers.on('click', function () {
            //left to you append cloned element only when needed (when there are are gonna be no more visible elements for slideshow, not at every click)
        $(appendtotop).after(addtotop);
    $(appendtobottom).after(addtobottom);
    gallery.width(gallery.width() + widthtoadd);
    if (gallery.is(':not(:animated)')) {                
        var cycle = false,
            delta = (this.id === "prev") ? -1 : 1;                    //there is something wrong on calculation of css left add for "prev" action
        gallery.animate({ left: "+=" + (imgwidth * delta) }, function () {
            current += delta;
            cycle = !!(current === 0 || current > len);
            if (cycle) {
                current = (current === 0) ? len : 1;
                gallery.css({ right: imgwidth });
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Here is my forked fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bzd5eutx/

As last comment i would say if writing that code from 0 doesn't sound like reinventing the wheel, assuming there are plenty of js libs for simple slideshows like that.

Comment: Thanks for your work, I will check it and remake it so it fits my needs :-)

Comment: You're wellcome :)